# How can I convert a Noma Ornamotion Christmas tree ornament motor to USB power?

Tags: resistors, motor, ac

I have a small motor that plugs into the light socket of a incandescent mini light set and spins an ornament. They were called [Ornamotion spinning motors.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001CJR78G)

[image]

[image]

Now that we're moving to LED, the LED sets just don't have the power to operate this motor, so I got to thinking: What if I could convert it to run via USB?

My understanding is that a set of mini lights are 120V AC with 48 light sockets (rounded up to 50.) That would mean a single mini light socket is 2.5V. I believe that a USB source is 5V.

Would I be right in assuming that if I added a resistor to reduce the voltage that would do the trick? If I added a second motor to the circuit, would it make up the difference in voltage?

Does anyone else have any ideas how I could power these things safely without using incandescent mini lights on my tree?

Comment: It's hard to imagine what specifically you're referring to (not sure what a "mini light" is in this context!); would you mind posting a photo of the whole contraption, installed in its place?

Comment: It would also help to give the part number, and any labelling, of the existing ``incandescent light``. This is to confirm the supply voltage and if AC or DC.

Comment: If the motor relies on the supply being AC then it won't work on a DC supply.

Comment: Sorry, by the mini incandescent Christmas lights. I mean like these: https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/for-living-indoor-100-mini-incandescent-lights-multi-1513479p.html#store=333

Comment: It's similar to this idea https://www.amazon.ca/Kurt-S-Adler-24-Inch-Twirl/dp/B07RWPLFF3

Comment: if it works with a 100 bulb string, then it operates at an effective voltage of ca 1.2 V, but with AC; which means you should be able to test whether it works with DC simply by connecting a simple 1.5 V battery.

Comment: Please show the instruction without hiding it with the motors. Suggestion by Marcus Muller to test with one 1.5V battery or two or more batteries in series (3v, 4.5V) is a good idea. It could work even if it's designed for AC.

Comment: If the plastic enclosure is not glued together you might try to snap one end off to view the motor and wiring. If the motor is wired with one or more diodes (converting AC to DC) you know it is a DC motor. If you read the full instruction sheet it may tell you the wattage of the device, from that you may be able to estimate the motor current and select a suitable power source.

Comment: The motor doesn't work with DC, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I did this a long time ago with transformers. Sorry, I don't remember the transformer part number, but I matched the voltage as close as I could. I may have used 1/2 of a center tap.

I also have some Hallmark animated ornaments that use a higher voltage (meant to be used with a string with fewer, higher voltage bulbs). So, I have 2 transformers in a metal box.

If you haven't worked with line voltages before, my method probably isn't for you. But, since not everyone is understanding the problem, I will offer my solution.

The motors may work with DC, you will need to experiment. I have many different ornament types, so I wanted a universal solution.

Edit: I found the box. Open circuit, one transformer puts out 3.2 VAC, the other puts out 4.2 VAC. The motors were connected to the lower voltage.

The motors will work with a wide range of incandescent strings. For a 35 bulb string the voltage would be 3.1 VAC. For a 50 bulb string the voltage would be 2.2 VAC. I believe that 100 bulb strings almost always actually had 2 strings of 50 bulbs.

Since low voltage transformers are difficult to find, I used a transformer with a dual 110/220 primary and wired it for 220 VAC effectively halving the output voltages. I am in the USA line is ~110 VAC.

Edit2: I have some of these same motors. I tested a motor with DC, it doesn't work. I tried 3 and 4 volts, both polarities. Same motor works fine with my circuit.

The transformer is probably a 6.3 VAC transformer with a 110/220 VAC primary, with the primary wired for 220 VAC.

Edit3: Mini incandescent Christmas bulbs are about 0.4 Watts. So, if they are 2.5 V bulbs, the bulb current is about 160 mA. The motor current must be similar for this entire scheme to work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiHAUz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>